# M1 Mac - Issue bringing up ElasticSearch. Cannot run jdk/bin/java

Tags: java, macos, docker, apple-m1

Have done a bit of searching to no avail.  Attempting to setup a project with an Elasticsearch docker container.  Works on my older intel MacBook but no luck so far with the new system.

```
elasticsearch    | Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper.
elasticsearch    |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
elasticsearch    |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.flagsFinal(JvmErgonomics.java:111)
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.finalJvmOptions(JvmErgonomics.java:88)
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:59)
elasticsearch    |  at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:95)
elasticsearch    | Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper.
elasticsearch    |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
elasticsearch    |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:319)
elasticsearch    |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:250)
elasticsearch    |  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
elasticsearch    |  ... 5 more
elasticsearch exited with code 1
```

Would greatly appreciate any help or pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ran into this too with the image from dockerhub, but it seems using the [official docker build from Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode) now works fine on my M1 Mac.

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
```

Comment: This solution fixed the problem!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fixed it for me as well on a M1 :-)

Comment: Version 7.10.2 :)

Comment: Interesting, thank you a lot, it works

Comment: ```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
```

```
$ docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java": error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 233, exit value: 1
```

Specifying `docker run --platform=linux/amd64` fails, any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

According to this comment: https://github.com/opendistro/for-elasticsearch-docs/issues/385#issuecomment-867198711 there are specific builds for Apple M1 with the suffix -arm64, example:

```
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.2-arm64
```

Answer (score 2):

For me below config worked on **M1 mac**

> docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:

  my-elasticsearch:
    container_name: my-elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.6
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    volumes:
      - my-elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elastiscsearch/data:rw
```

Answer (score 0):

Change elasticsearch version from 7.5.1 to 7.10.2.
(ELK_VERSION=7.10.2)