# Cannot start elasticsearch image M1 Apple

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch

Cannot start Elastic search on Apple M1. I have tried all suggestions I've found on stackoverflow. Moreover, when I go to elasticsearch folder in the path **/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java** it does not exist.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need the `--platform` flag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65994297/4604579

Comment: Without or with platform I get the same result, platform was only another attempt.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the antiquated 7.10.2 by the way?

Comment: Just because this was another attempt from the stack. New versions give the same result btw.

Comment: Any thoughts? Because I've already tried 10+ different versions of elastic search and still get always the same error. My jdk version is 17.0.8

Comment: What version of Docker do you have?

Comment: Have already solved by removing check from Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon in Docker settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by removing checkmark from Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon in Docker settings